# C++ control reaches end of non-void function

Tags: c++

I have a function, which looks something like this:

```
ClassA& ClassB::Check(int x){
    //some calculations in a loop, if a condition is met, a reference to a ClassA object is given
}
```

I'm getting the "control reaches end of non-void function" error. As far as I understand, this is because, the function wont always return something, am I right?

The function is getting the mouse coordinates and checking witch objects was selected. If something was selected, then do stuff, otherwise do nothing.

What would be the best option to solve this? Should I create and return an object with some kind of flag to check against?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should not be returning a reference in this case but rather a pointer.  In case there is no object to return, you should return 0.  Another option to consider is to stick with returning a reference, but if you cannot for some reason, throw an exception.

Comment: In the pointer case, you might want to return NULL rather than 0, since it's more descriptive (though they're equivalent in this case).

Comment: Hm, I guess the case where nothing was selected is not so "exceptional" that throwing an exception is the right thing to do here.

Comment: @Cyanfish - if you have access to C++11 you should be returning nullptr which has better type safety.  Actually in this particular case you might even want to return a std::unique_ptr that potentially contains a nullptr, depending on the ownership situation of the return value.

Comment: Maybe there's a default object which can be returned, aka the null-object-pattern...

Answer (score 2):

Following the [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles (especially the "S" = single responsibility), you may consider to split this up into 2 functions:

- one doing the check and returning a `bool` to signal if the check was successful or not, and
- one to request the reference to the `classA` object.

Currently, yur current function has two responsibilities (checking **and** returning a related object).

Or you rename your function to `GetSelectedObject`, in which case the first part of @JoelFan's answer is fine. This changes the point of view about the responsibility of that function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, will keep those principles in mind